# Limesurvey : comfirm a fields

Tags: php, survey, limesurvey

I have two fields on a survey, mail and confirmail.

The second fields is only to insure than our first field is entered correctly, but I can't find a validation rule allowing me to check the confirmail according to the mail field.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Give an example when you need it, or what the second field should be containing exactly? you have built in 'emailstatus' that returns bounces, optouts and any other problem with emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the question code for the first question is "mail", you can place something like this in the "Question validation equation" field of the second question:

```
this == mail
```

Then, something like this in the "Question validation tip" field:

```
{if(this != mail, 'The email addresses do not match!', '')}
```

Comment: the Question validation equation in the "advanced fields options"  zone ?